# Calculate MD5 for a long string

Tags: sql-server, hash

When calling HASHBYTES with long string I am getting

```
Msg 8152, Level 16, State 10, Line 11
String or binary data would be truncated.
```

I am trying to calculate the MD5 hash for multiple fields together so I can compare objects,
Is there anyway around this?

Comment: Perhaps you can share your code? That error message is from an insert. AFAIK there is no limit to the length of the input to MD5. I just tried it with a massive amount of input and it works fine.

Comment: From the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174415.aspx), there is a limit on the return value of 8000 bytes.  If your input would cause this to be exceeded, then you might be out of luck.  But, do you really need to be using so many fields to compute a hashcode?

Comment: @SeanLange The maximum return size appears to be 8K, q.v. my comment above.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen yes but it simply truncates the input to 8k so this error is not possible from HASHBYTES. Of course that makes the output somewhat useless. :)

Comment: Please show us the query/code which generated this error.

Comment: you can try SQLCLR

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you're using SQL Server 2008 or above, use the CHECKSUM function.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189788.aspx

> CHECKSUM computes a hash value, called the checksum, over its list of arguments. The hash value is intended for use in building hash indexes. If the arguments to CHECKSUM are columns, and an index is built over the computed CHECKSUM value, the result is a hash index. This can be used for equality searches over the columns.
>
> CHECKSUM returns an error if any column is of noncomparable data type. Noncomparable data types are text, ntext, image, XML, and cursor, and also sql_variant with any one of the preceding types as its base type.

Answer (score 1):

As @TimBiegeleisen said. SQL Server has an 8k bytes limitation on HASHBYTES.

However, it looks like that SQL Server 2016 and forward **don't** have this limitation.

> For SQL Server 2014 (12.x) and earlier, allowed input values are
>   limited to 8000 bytes.
>   https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/hashbytes-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017